# Laravel Schema Builder Invoke via CLI?

Tags: sql, schema, database-schema, laravel

Is there any way to use Laravel's Schema Builder from the command line? Right now I have it set up so that an admin panel is able to rebuild tables, but is there some way to build schemas from the command?

I think a better question would be, how would I require_once the autoloader so I can simply

```
php myschema.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a [migration](http://laravel.com/docs/database/migrations) or an [artisan task](http://laravel.com/docs/artisan/tasks) to handle it.  See the documentation at the respective links for more information.  In either case, you will then be able to use Schema and call Laravel from the command line with either `php artisan migrate` or `php artisan task` depending on which you created.